# changing plus sign to minus when collapsed

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
 <div style="border:1px solid red;width:200px;">
<div class="wpsc_categorisation_group">
    <ul class="wpsc_categories wpsc_top_level_categories">
        <li><a href="link">main link 1</a>
            <ul class="wpsc_second_level_categories">
                <li><a>test 1</a></li>
                <li><a>test 2</a></li>
                <li><a>test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear_category_group"></div>
</div>
<div class="wpsc_categorisation_group">
    <ul class="wpsc_categories wpsc_top_level_categories">
        <li><a href="link2">main link 2</a>
            <ul class="wpsc_second_level_categories">
                <li><a>test 1</a></li>
                <li><a>test 2</a></li>
                <li><a>test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear_category_group"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
span.CatExpander {float:right;cursor:pointer;}
.wpsc_second_level_categories {display:none;}
```

jQuery

```
//<![CDATA[
(function($)
{
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".wpsc_top_level_categories > li:has(ul)").prepend("<span class=\"CatExpander\">[+]</span>");

$(".CatExpander").click(function()
{
$(this).toggleClass("CatExpanded").siblings("ul").slideToggle(500);
return false;
}).eq(0).addClass("CatExpanded").end().slice(1).siblings("ul").hide();
});
})(jQuery);
//]]>
```

My question is How can I make the plus sign change to minus sign when collapsed, Im using an accordion style jquery

here is My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nwbY7/28/

Answer (score 3):

Modify your jquery code to add this line

```
$(this).html($(this).html()=="[+]"?"[-]":"[+]");
```

Here is the complete function

```
//<![CDATA[
(function($)
{
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".wpsc_top_level_categories > li:has(ul)").prepend("<span class=\"CatExpander\">[+]</span>");

$(".CatExpander").click(function()
{
    $(this).html($(this).html()=="[+]"?"[-]":"[+]");
    $(this).toggleClass("CatExpanded").siblings("ul").slideToggle(500);
    return false;
}).eq(0).addClass("CatExpanded").end().slice(1).siblings("ul").hide();
});
})(jQuery);
//]]>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) test to change the symbol to the appropriate value:

```
$(this).text($(this).hasClass("CatExpanded") ? "[-]" : "[+]");
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/2RJ5V/

Comment: what is the difference between yours and other answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you're complicating things too much. If you add the span in html you can get rid of some code.

```
<li><a href="link">main link 1</a><span>[+]</span>
```

Then you can simplify your JavaScript to this:

```
$('.wpsc_categories span').click(function(){
    var $ul = $(this).next();
    $(this).html( $ul.is(':visible') ? '[+]' : '[&ndash;]');
    $ul.slideToggle();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/nwbY7/34/